# Samples on kubernetes golang client

Tags: go, client, kubernetes

I`m trying to create replication controllers, services etc from the golang client. ("github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned") However I cannot find any documentation on how to do so.

I found this:

r, err := c.ReplicationControllers(api.NamespaceDefault).Create(rep)

But I don`t know where to put the yml data etc. Anyone who found documentation or has some sample code that I could get started with ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I put together a sample Kubernetes client in Go that allows to query the API version and make a sample NGINX deployment. Maybe it's helpful to you: https://github.com/timoreimann/kubernetes-goclient-example

Note that it doesn't use replication controllers (which, by the way, have been replaced by [replica sets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/replicasets/) by now) but uses the newer [Deployments API](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/). I also don't feed in YAML files; instead, I define everything programmatically. Reading YAML files and unmarshalling them into Kubernetes structs should be a fairly straight-forward thing to do though.

Comment: Sir, I have a question, I am trying to run the most simple program, the example one, and I have not changed a single line of code. I am doing `glide init` which asks me few questions and generates the glide.yml file.Then, at the time when I am trying to do `glide up` it can not get the packages. What it says is something like this - `Error scanning k8s.io/client-go/1.5/kubernetes: open /Users/shubhadeeproychowdhury/.glide/cache/src/https-k8s.io-client-go/1.5/kubernetes: no such file or directory` This does not change if I am trying to do a glide get k8s.io/client-go/1.5/ also. I am getting mad