# not able to get the client-go from k8s

Tags: go, client, kubernetes

I have tried all the possible paths that I can think of, I am not able to put the base examples to work with kubernetes and Go lang. I am new to all the godeps, gilde, govendor thing, I will give myself that, but even then I have no idea how can I simply get this package which is referenced like this in the example file -

```
"k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/pkg/api"
    "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/tools/clientcmd"
```

And to be precise, this is what is written here - https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/release-1.5

> How to get it
>
> You can go get to get a release of client-go, e.g., go get
>   k8s.io/client-go/1.4/... or go get k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes.

Now when I do this. This is the output -

> warning: "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/..." matched no packages can't load
>   package: package .: no buildable Go source files in
>   /Users/shubhadeeproychowdhury/projects/go/src

Although it clones things in a directory called k8s under src in my GOPATH.

Finally in the same link they are talking about dependency management and things, where they refer to a directory 1.4 under the client-do directory. I can not see that directory anywhere in the cloned k8s directory.

I have been trying to install the basic packages and run the example codes for two days now, I can't. I really feel awkward and strange. Can any one please help me with a clear step by step instructions on how to get started?

Note - 1: I have several other Go projects and I have not used dependency management so far. I do not want to mess up my other projects in order to try to install and use this one. I am sure there is way.

Note - 2: I have found this link - [Samples on kubernetes golang client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135933/samples-on-kubernetes-golang-client) But it does not explain to me how to get over the primary hurdle to get it in my Go workspace and run the example code.

Kubernetes people, if you are listening, please be a little bit more elaborate in your documentation if possible. I will be happy to lend a hand in that, it is just that I do not know how to take the frist step at this point of time.

Please help

Comment: From the master README: `If you use go get to get client-go, you will get the unstable master branch! You can git checkout a stable branch.`
Without using any dependency management or vendoring tools, just checkout the version branch you want locally. The correct subdirectory will be there.

Comment: I tired that. This is what I did @JimB - 1.> I git clone the repo (github.com/kubernetes/client-go), 2.> I fetched the release-1.5 branch, 3.> I git checkout to that branch. You see the problem is still there. The example folder of that branch actually refers import from this - "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/" path. It is of course not present unless I personally cut paste that 1.5 (or 1.4) directory into a new dir tree which is like this - src/k8s.io I find this is strange. I am sure there is some way. I just need to understand / get a step by step instructions to get started.

Comment: very strange it might sound, copying that folder manually in a dir tree like what I said above seems to be working. I am not sure, I have to test it properly yet.

Comment: It works like that. And once I created that dir tree manually govendor works perfectly also! I am not sure if I am missing something or there is a breaking change in the implementation that is not reflected yet in documentation or the change is rightly reflected but the code base does not work or ... well I am a bit confused as you can see. But at least I could put it work in the way I described in my first comment.

Comment: you should not change the k8s.io package code at all. If the examples were written for the 1.4 branch, then checkout the 1.4 branch. By copying the 1.5 branch to the 1.4 directory you're breaking whatever API changes were made between those versions.

Comment: I am not doing that. I copied the 1.5 codes to 1.5 directory and then following the examples I am able to write a basic client with 1.5 code. I am not using 1.4 at all. Sorry  if that was not clear before.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue myself. Previously all I needed to do was `go get k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes` and I was good to go. Now that fails with:

```
package k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes: cannot find package "k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes" in any of:
```

While documentation mentions use of package management tools I did not want to use them as there is already vendor directory from Go itself. I was able to resolve the issue by doing this:

1. Create `vendor` directory in your project root.
2. In vendor directory create `k8s.io` directory. This is to fix references from the library to itself.
3. In `k8s.io` directory do `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go.git`
4. In `client-go` directory do `git checkout v1.5.0` (or the version you want). Checkout is important as v1.4/v1.5 are only in specific commits. Master for example no longer have these.
5. In your project import with `k8s.io/client-go/1.5/kubernetes`

Comment: what I ended up doing and what I tried to explain in my comments is exactly the similar process. Although I cloned and checked out the repo in a different directory than the vendor and then used govendor and it could detect it (as the proper dir tree, as you mentioned also, exists) and then it copies it for me in my vendor dir. But your method is also fine. And as it is a step by step guide, it is better to understand. Hope this will help people who are stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do a glide get [package-name], assuming you already have a glide.yaml present.
In your case glide get k8s.io/client-go/1.4/kubernetes should do the trick.